# How to calculate transaction fee

Tags: nearprotocol

I want to  empty my transactable balance,but alwalys got LackofBalance error.

I've used gas price* gas limit and ransfer_cost + create_account_cost + add_key_cost.full_access_cost by
https://nomicon.io/GenesisConfig/RuntimeFeeConfig/ActionCreationConfig#transfer_cost to calculate fee and max transaction amount.None of them work well.

Comment: Please post your code in your question rather than linking to it in an external site. Questions should be self-contained where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your account is linked to the [NEAR wallet](https://wallet.near.org/), you can use `Send MAX` to transfer as much NEAR balance as possible. After that operation your account will be, in some sense, locked since you need to receive funds from someone to continue operating with it.

An alternative to getting **ALL** the funds from your account is deleting it and set another account as the target where all funds should go. This can be done via [near-cli](https://github.com/near/near-cli) using `near delete tobedestroyed.near receiver.near`